# How create a DefaultTableModel with data from text file

Tags: java, defaulttablemodel

**I have this test file [text_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG6pz.png)
My table view is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b6uP.png)
I want suit each row with each column(first_row-first_column,second_row-second_column, etc..) Where is error?**

```
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = "";
        int counter = 0;
        String title = "";
        String author = "";
        String price = "";
        try {
            while ((line  = infile.readLine()) != null) {
                ++counter;

                if (counter == 1) {
                    title = line;
                } else if (counter == 2) {
                    author = line;
                } else if (counter == 3) {
                    price = line;
                    SimpleBook sb = new SimpleBook(title, author, price);
                    bookList.add(sb);
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleBookList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in reading the file, because you read line by line not read all lines

```
        int counter = 0;
        String title = "", author = "";
        double price = 0.0;
        while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null) {
            ++counter;
            if (counter == 1)
                title = line;
            else if (counter == 2)
                author = line;
            else if (counter == 3) {
                price = Double.parseDouble(line);
                SimpleBook sb = new SimpleBook(title, author, price);
                bookList.add(sb);
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

, or you can check **readAllLines** from [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path))

Comment: When in text file let one line ("\n") and i copy paste the same data (for example),then the second row or third or fourth is wrong(first row suit with second..etc.)ho can fix these

Comment: Do you mean that the rows don't have the same columns?

Comment: yes...first row suit with second column etc..i want first row with first column etc

Comment: could you put some data as an example!

Comment: i want text file such above but data separated by one space line

Comment: So now data separated by space and you have 3 columns for each row?

Comment: how can put pic

Comment: I don't know, if I got you correctly I have updated the code

Comment: i have A B C D E onebelow to other..i let one space line and i have again A B C D E one below to other

Comment: Look..My mistake..my test file has A B 3.00 one below to other..i let one space line below to 3.00 and i put again the same data one below to other..

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class SimpleBookList {

    private ArrayList<SimpleBook> bookList;

    public SimpleBookList() {
        bookList = new ArrayList<SimpleBook>();
    }

    public void add(SimpleBook sb) {
        bookList.add(sb);
    }

    public ArrayList<SimpleBook> getBooks() {
        return bookList;
    }

    public void readFromTxt(String filename) {
        File file = new File(filename);
        FileReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = "";
        int counter = 0;
        String title = "";
        String author = "";
        String price = "";
        try {
            while ((line  = infile.readLine()) != null) {
                ++counter;
                if (counter == 1) {
                    title = line;
                } else if (counter == 2) {
                    author = line;
                } else if (counter == 3) {
                    price = line;
                    SimpleBook sb = new SimpleBook(title, author, price);
                    bookList.add(sb);
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleBookList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If this isn't an answer, it should have been edited into the question.